# Symfony 6 on IIS server 10 : routing get the log, not the result of the endpoint

Tags: symfony, iis, configuration, url-routing, api-platform.com

I'm trying to put my application with symfony6 and Api platform 3 on a IIS server. On the localhost there is no problem. On the /api i can get my documentation and i can call my endpoints. But when i call the online version of my api i get a kind of log, not the result of my endpoint.

```
[info] Matched route "api_entrypoint".
[debug] Checking for authenticator support.
[debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure".
[debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest".
[debug] Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest".
...
```

My website point in the public file, on the index.php. I've tried a lot of web.config i use this one actually :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
         <rules>
        <rule name="Rewriter" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\\.php|favicon\\.ico)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My endpoints are recognize, just the result is not what i expect, logs instead of json result of the EP.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, you need to check the configuration information of routing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, and although I'm not exactly sure what was causing the problem, I managed to solve it by following these steps. I thought I'd share them with you in case they might be helpful:

1. When I tried to deploy my project in IIS on my local computer, I had to adjust the security settings for the "my_project" folder, and that resolved the issue.
2. However, when I attempted to deploy the project on my real server, I applied the same security settings, but it didn't work. After some further troubleshooting, I found that adding the "Symfony/monolog-bundle" bundle with the command "`composer require Symfony/monolog-bundle`" made everything work correctly.

I understand that the root cause of the problem might vary for different scenarios. But since this solution worked for me when I was struggling to find any answers online, I wanted to share these steps with you.

I hope this helps!